# Why was this "relieved" petty officer still relaying orders down the chain of command?

Tags: the-hunt-for-red-october

[image]

At [1:00](https://youtu.be/4unk6siO-tI?t=60), Ramius berates a petty officer "You're relieved" as quoted below.

[image]

But at 1:10, you can see that same officer relaying Ramius's new order down the chain of command, so how was he "relieved"? This scene doesn't fit [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-to-relieve-officer-in-military-context).

[Hunt For Red October Script - transcript from the screenplay and/or Alec Baldwin as Jack Ryan movie](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/h/hunt-for-red-october-script.html)

> Captain, we're out of position by a boat length.
> Torpedo impact now seconds.
> Sound collision.
> Sound collision.
> We're out of the lane!
> **You're relieved.**
> Borodin?
> Right full rudder!
> Reverse starboard engine!
> Right full rudder.
> All back starboard shaft.

Comment: Once again, can I suggest that you capture the screenshots _without youtube controls, clip titles and view counts_.  It clutters the readability of your questions, and may be contributing towards the downvotes you are getting.  If these clips are on youtube, you can link the videos themselves with the exact time you want to show - and they will play in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why was this “relieved” petty officer still relaying orders down the chain of command?

### Why not?

Although "relieved" (of what isn't actually clear) he's now obeying (or at least merely relaying) orders instead of questioning them.

Obviously the scene is intended to ratchet tension and indicate that Ramius' tactical awareness and knowledge is superior to his junior officers.

In real life it's likely that the relieved officer would have been told to leave the bridge/control room pending disciplinary proceedings.